# Preg_match isn't working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this PHP preg_match code that's suppose to only allow a-z (Capital and lowercase) 0-9 and underscores

But when I try signing up with the username "Rizon" it says: 
Only valid characters are allowed.

Here's the code:

```
if (!preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]_",$_POST['username'])) {
$_SESSION['error']['username'] = "Only valid characters are allowed."; 
}
```

How can I fix the preg_match so it will allow usernames such as "Rizon" and usernames with uppercase and/or lowercase letters and/or numbers and/or underscores?

Comment: You have no delimiters. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick (you need to also check that username **only** contains your pattern)

```
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/",$_POST['username']))
```

Without adding `^` (start match) and `$` (end match) your regular expression will only validate if a pattern is included.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/",$_POST['username']);
```

or

```
!preg_match("/[a-z0-9_]+/i",$_POST['username']);
```

Comment: or with the case insensitive flag you could use `/[a-z0-9_]+/i`

Comment: Or if you want them to start with a letter, be at least 3 chars long, not end with underscore: '/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/'

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be the easiest regex.

```
if (!preg_match("~^\w+$~",$_POST['username'])) {
     $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "Only valid characters are allowed."; 
}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rG3sJ3/1

`\w` is any character a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and an underscore. `+` is one or more characters.

`^` is the start of the string, `$` is the end. Check the regex101 link for testing and more detailed description.

Links:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Comment: \w can also allow for locale specific characters.

Comment: This is probably the best answer but I'm not upvoting a regex that has `~` as a delimiter.

Comment: @pguardiario whats wrong with the `~` as a delimiter?

Comment: @pguardiario In appearance or coding practice? I have never had an issue using `~` as a delimiter. The `/` though will cause an issue when dealing with URLS, paths, equations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're missing delimiters for your regular expression. You could use `/` or `#` or any other of [the available ones](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).
Next by the way you've declared the pattern to match again, it would translate to "match a single alphanumeric symbol followed by underscore".
So as already suggested use

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

as a regex instead and use pattern delimiters

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/',$_POST['username'])
```

You could also use the [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `i` for case insensitive

```
preg_match('/[a-z0-9_]+/i',$_POST['username'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Come to think of it you probably want to do:

```
if (preg_match("/\W/",$_POST['username'])) { // check for non-word chars
  $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "Only valid characters are allowed."; 
}
```

And a separate validation for length:

```
if (!preg_match("/^.{6,8}$/",$_POST['username'])) { // check for length
  $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "6 to 8 letters please"; 
}
```